# Replace multiple spaces with one space in txt files using batch

Tags: batch

Here is what Ive got

```
    @ECHO OFF
   SETLOCAL
   ::
   :: delete first line/lines
   :: and replace each occurrence of 2 or more spaces
   :: by a delimiter
   ::
   DEL outfile.txt   2>nul /F /Q
   :: replace with ->
   SET delim= 
   :: set number of lines to delete 
   FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%i IN (Text.txt) DO (
   SET line=%%i
   (SET newline=)
   SET count=0
   CALL :change
   )
   GOTO :eof

   :CHANGE
   SET c1=%line:~0,1%
   SET line=%line:~1%
   IF "%c1%"==" " (SET /a count+=1) ELSE (
   IF %count%==0 (SET newline=%newline%%c1%) ELSE (
   IF %count%==1 (SET newline=%newline% %c1%) ELSE (
   SET newline=%newline%%delim%%c1%)
   SET count=0
   )
   )
   IF DEFINED line GOTO CHANGE
   ::
   :: You may want to preserve trailing spaces
   :: or convert them...
   ::
   IF %count%==0 GOTO print
   IF %count%==1 SET newline=%newline% &GOTO print
   SET newline=%newline%%delim%
   :PRINT
   >>outfile.txt ECHO %newline%
   GOTO :eof
```

Here is an example of file

```
    P1 something             232
2      232  233
10     232  232
2312   232  232
231    232 323
```

I no longer need to delete the first line, can some 1 help me figure out how to replace the spaces winought skiping the first line/lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 11, replace:

```
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%i IN (Text.txt) DO (
```

with

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (Text.txt) DO (
```

To allow the use of quotes for filenames with spaces, [per this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5006393/3395469), you can use the `usebackq` option:

```
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%i IN ("text 2.txt") DO (
```

Comment: is there any way to use files with spaces in theyr name? 
E.G. "New Text File.txt" (usualy quotation marks are the answer, but it seams not for this time)

Comment: Upated my answer. Long story short, you can use the `usebackq` option. Had to look that one up. =)